# Exchange authorization code for tokens in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, token, google-oauth

I'm trying so badly to implement OAuth 2.0 Playground on my client's website.

using JavaScript like:

```js
gapi.analytics.ready(function () {
            gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
                clientid: '144574795319-rqkxt6crq4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                serverAuth: {
                    access_token: 'ya29.xxxxgWu_PPW13J'
                }                  
            });

            var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                    'ids': 'ga:86683126',
                    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                    'end-date': 'yesterday',
                    'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:users',
                    'dimensions': 'ga:date'
                },
                chart: {
                    'container': 'chart-1-container',
                    'type': 'LINE',
                    'options': {
                        'width': '100%'
                    }
                }
            });

            dataChart1.execute();
        });
```

Works fine, since I already generated the access_token, but the token has a expiration time. So I try to refresh it using:

```js
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token'; 
        var payload = {
            client_secret: 'Zo4juYxxxxxx0KUBJW',
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: '1KjRl4ncrcEY2gaEWxxxxXSv_LjCrQ',
            client_id: '0000-rqkxxxxxt6crq4.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        };

        $.post(url, {
           form: payload
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            alert(body);//just to test if i have some return
        });
```

Doesn't work. I don't know what else I could do to correct it.